# Inserting Horizontal Line within Paragraph [ Reportlab ]

Tags: python, django, pdf, reportlab, paragraph

I seen a few example code which add a horizontal line using a Table, however I was wondering if there a faster way using the Paragraph instead. I look into the reportlab docs, however I could find anything.

So my question is, is it possible to add a horizontal line using Paragraph instead?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The fastest way is probably using the `HRFlowable` this flowable attempt to mimic the behavior of the HTML `<HR>`  just to give you an indication, this is how it looks in HTML:

---

As this function is not documented the best I can do is refer you to the [source code](https://hg.reportlab.com/hg-public/reportlab/file/61ba11e7d143/src/reportlab/platypus/flowables.py#l851) which show all options that are available.

Below my own attempt of documenting this flowable

> **HRFlowable**(width="80%", thickness=1, lineCap='round', color=lightgrey, spaceBefore=1, spaceAfter=1, hAlign='CENTER', vAlign='BOTTOM', dash=None)
>
> **width**: Width of the horizontal line
> **thickness**: Height of the horizontal line
> **lineCap**: Determines whether a terminating line ends
> in a square exactly at the vertex, a square over the vertex or a half circle over the vertex.
> **color**: Straight forward
> **spaceBefore**: ??? *Isn't used in the source code*
> **spaceAfter**: ??? *Isn't used in the source code*
> **hAlign**: ??? *Isn't used in the source code*
> **vAlign**: ??? *Isn't used in the source code*
> **dash**: Allows the line to be broken into dots or dashes.

Comment: Thank you, I notice they left quite alot out from the documentation. I probably start Reverse Engineering everything now. Thank for the answer ;)

Comment: spaceBefore/spaceAfter (and likely hAlign/vAlign) are used by the Flowable parent class

Comment: Additional examples found online: https://programtalk.com/python-examples/reportlab.platypus.flowables.HRFlowable/